# WSO2EI integrate hello world api

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm just starting out with cloud technology and I'm trying to implement a simple hello world example. I'm using the new wso2 enterprise integration server. I'm trying to setup a simple API.

I've implemented 1 endpoint:

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <address uri="http://192.168.1.100:9191/v1/hello">
      <suspendOnFailure>
         <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
       </suspendOnFailure>
       <markForSuspension>
         <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
          <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
      </markForSuspension>
   </address>
</endpoint>
```

I've implemented 2 sequences:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="HelloWorldIN" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <send>
        <endpoint key="gov:/HelloWorld"/>
    </send>
</sequence>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="HelloWorldOUT" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <send/>
</sequence>
```

and finally the API itself

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="HelloWorld" context="/helloworld" hostname="192.168.1.100" port="9191">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/v1/hello" inSequence="HelloWorldIN" outSequence="HelloWorldOUT"/>
</api>
```

---

When I do a GET (http://192.168.1.162:8280/helloworld/v1/hello )request to this API, I get a 202 accepted response, no data. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
This is the complete configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <registry provider="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.registry.WSO2Registry">
        <parameter name="cachableDuration">15000</parameter>
    </registry>
    <taskManager provider="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.ntask.NTaskTaskManager"/>
    <sequence name="HelloWorldOUT">
        <send buildmessage="true"/>
    </sequence>
     <sequence name="fault">
         <!-- Log the message at the full log level with the ERROR_MESSAGE and the ERROR_CODE-->
        <log level="full">
             <property name="MESSAGE" value="Executing default 'fault' sequence"/>
             <property expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')" name="ERROR_CODE"/>
             <property expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')" name="ERROR_MESSAGE"/>
          </log>
         <!-- Drops the messages by default if there is a fault -->
         <drop/>
     </sequence>
     <sequence name="main">
         <in>
             <!-- Log all messages passing through -->
             <log level="full"/>
             <!-- ensure that the default configuration only sends if it is one of samples -->
             <!-- Otherwise Synapse would be an open proxy by default (BAD!)               -->
             <filter regex="http://localhost:9000.*" source="get-property('To')">
                 <!-- Send the messages where they have been sent (i.e. implicit "To" EPR) -->
                 <send/>
             </filter>
         </in>
         <out>
             <send/>
         </out>
         <description>The main sequence for the message mediation</description>
     </sequence>
     <sequence name="HelloWorldIN">
         <send>
             <endpoint name="gov//HelloWorld">
                 <address uri="http://192.168.1.100:9191/v1/hello"/>
             </endpoint>
         </send>
     </sequence>
     <api context="/helloworld" hostname="192.168.1.100"
    name="HelloWorld" port="9191" statistics="enable" trace="enable">
         <resource inSequence="HelloWorldIN" methods="GET"
        outSequence="HelloWorldOUT" uri-template="*"/>
     </api>
     <!-- You can add any flat sequences, endpoints, etc.. to this synapse.xml file if you do
*not* want to keep the artifacts in several files -->
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is change the main sequence. I've routed it to my in sequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="main" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <in>
        <!-- Log all messages passing through -->
        <log level="full"/>
        <!-- ensure that the default configuration only sends if it is one of samples -->
        <!-- Otherwise Synapse would be an open proxy by default (BAD!)               -->
        <filter regex="http://localhost:9000.*"
        source="get-property('To')" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
            <then>
                <!-- Send the messages where they have been sent (i.e. implicit "To" EPR) -->
                <send/>
            </then>
            <else>
                <log/>
                <sequence key="gov:/HelloWorldIN"/>
            </else>
        </filter>
    </in>
    <out>
        <send/>
    </out>
    <description>The main sequence for the message mediation</description>
</sequence>
```

Make sure your api uses meaningful names. This makes it easier to configure the esb. If your api listenes on the same subdomain, no URL rewrite mediator is needed. I've changed the context of my API to accomplish this.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="HelloWorld" context="/hello" hostname="192.168.1.100" port="9191">
   <resource methods="GET" inSequence="HelloWorldIN" outSequence="HelloWorldOUT"/>
</api>
```